# Why does adding id="ad_a" to a HTML element sometimes make it invisible in Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: html

I bring to you a simple snippet of HTML:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD></HEAD>
<BODY>
<div id="ad_a">                 
    test DIV
</div>

test BODY

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Yeah, there's no doctype or what have you, but none of that seems to matter for this strange behavior.

Can anybody please tell me why calling my div `id="ad_(ANYTHING HERE)"` hides everything inside this div? it just.. disappears.. It shows up in the page source but it doesn't show up on the loaded page..

I first noticed this in Google Chrome. Firefox seems to ignore it (for me at least, but my friend says it happens in his FF) my Internet Explorer 9 also ignores this div name and shows its content on the page.

What is going on and why does it do this?

Is this a commonly used thing? If so, what does it do?

Comment: I'm going out on a limb here, but could an ad-blocking extension be interpreting the `ad_` prefix as an advertisement and hiding it? I just ran the code in Chrome with all extensions disabled and it shows up as intended.

Comment: This is definitely not a HTML problem, as johnluetke already suggested. Most probable, the hiding is done by some ad-blocking extensions in those browsers.

Comment: Do you have any documentation that says single quotes are not valid ?

Comment: @Joseph: single quotes a perfectly valid. Not the general style which is used, but valid.

Comment: @Chris Morgan: single quotes ARE valid: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2 , just not in xHTML, and it's not what most people are accustomed to using. That's why I suggested he change it. I was not suggesting that it might somehow be causing the problem...

Comment: @johnluetke you were absolutely right. disabling Ad block on my chrome does not hide the div. likewise, my friend must have ad block on his Firefox. Please make an answer and I shall accept it. (I believe this one goes to John for quickest answer?) Quite the simple question indeed but useful to know, I think. I spent a day trying to figure this one out.. next time I'll disable plugins first. xD

Comment: @Joseph I did say not to worry about syntax and rules for a moment in my question, but I was not aware that single quotes were not valid in xHTML so I'll be more careful from now on as this is what I normally code in, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @Partack done. much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Posting comment as answer at OP's request)

> I'm going out on a limb here, but could an ad-blocking extension be interpreting the ad_ prefix as an advertisement and hiding it? I just ran the code in Chrome with all extensions disabled and it shows up as intended

Comment: The culprit was my ad blocker extension. Ad blocker is quite a popular extension/plugin so it would make sense to never call a div ad_anything for this reason. Many thanks.